# Trouble understanding Java generic types, trying to build an array queue but getting lots of incompatible type errors

Tags: java, queue, generic-list, incompatibletypeerror

Here's my code:

```
public class ArrayQueue<E> implements QueueInterface<E> {

   private int front = -1;
   private int rear = -1;
   private E[] array; 
   private int manyItems;

   // constructor
   public ArrayQueue() {
      array = (E[]) new Object[5];
   } // end constructor method

   public void enqueue(E e) {
      if (rear == -1) {
         front = rear = e; // **this line gives an incompatible type error**
      } // end if

      if (rear + 1 > (array.length - 1) ) {
         E[] temp;
         temp = (E[]) new Object[array.length * 2];
         for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            temp[i] = array[i];
         } // end for loop
         array = temp;
         array[rear + 1] = e;
         rear = rear + 1;
      } // end if

      else {
         array[rear + 1] = e;
         rear = rear + 1;
      } // end else

   } // end enqueue method

   public E dequeue() {
      if (front == -1) {
         throw new IllegalStateException("The queue is empty, cannot dequeue");
      } // end if

      E e = front; // **this line gives an incompatible type error**
      front = front + 1;

      return e;

   } // end dequeue method

   public E front() {
      if (front == -1) {
         throw new IllegalStateException("The queue is empty, cannot return front");
      } // end if

      E e = front; // **this line gives an incompatible type error**

      return e;

   } // end front method

} // end ArrayQueue class
```

I'm confused what I'm supposed to do since these methods are based off an interface which I cannot change so can't change the methods to return an int. Furthermore I thought generic types could hold any sort of data, both primitive and Objects.

I am quite confused on what this means:

```
E e = front;
```

This is one of the lines of code I was given to work with. So the large E conveys that little e will be a variable of generic type? I just used this exact line with a Linked List queue and it worked fine since the e was an object node and not an integer. But why can't it take an int? And since it can't, how am I supposed to return an int into a method that requires a generic return type?

Comment: `E` means any reference type.  But you are writing code that would force `E` to be `int`.  Aside from the fact that `int` is not a reference type, this undermines the whole point of using generics.

Comment: In `array[rear + 1] = e;` you are using `rear` as an index into the `array` - maybe you should be doing the same with `front`? Meaning, you should write `E e = array[front];`